# Не получается вывести определенные категории

Tags: php, yii2

Всем здрасте.

Не могу понять как мне вывести определенные категории. Когда я перехожу на какую ту категорию, то у меня выводятся все товары из разных категории, как бы все в кучу. Я не могу понять где принимать $id что бы передать ту выбранную категорию и там например можно было делать фильтрацию товара по той категории который выбрал пользователь.

Раньше вот так выводилась http://site.loc/category/index?id=18

CategoryController это было раньше без model search

```
    public function actionIndex($id)
{
    $query = ProductPit::getProductByStatus($id);
    $countQuery = clone $query;

    $pagination = new Pagination(
        [
            'defaultPageSize' => 21,
            'totalCount' => $countQuery->count(),
            'forcePageParam' => false,
            'pageSizeParam' => false
        ]
    );

    $models = $countQuery
        ->offset($pagination->offset)
        ->limit($pagination->limit)
        ->all();

    if (empty($models)) {
        throw new HttpException(404, 'Категория не найдена');
    }

    return $this->render('post', [
 'models' => $models, 
 'pagination' => $pagination
]);
}
```

А сейчас у меня model search и CategoryController такой код, а также я использую listView

```
    public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new ProductPitSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, это нужно сделать в коде `ProductPitSearch` в методе `search()`, там формируется запрос и возвращается `$dataProvider`, там же и нужно добавить проверку на категорию, её `id` должен быть в GET параметрах, которые получаются через `Yii::$app->request->queryParams`